# how to automatically choose proxy server used in the browser according to different URL

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I have a set of proxy servers available, say one in China, one in USA, and one in Hong Kong. I   hope the web browser, say Chrome, can choose these proxy servers automatically according to some type of configuration files. For example, the configuration file indicates that when connecting websites such as A, B, C, the browser should choose proxy server in China; when connecting websites such as D, E, the browser should choose proxy server in USA.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for stackoverflow. Consider moving to  [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: You probably want to use proxy auto-config: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Proxy Switchy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchy/caehdcpeofiiigpdhbabniblemipncjj), your can use rules to define proxy for specific url pattern.